# java : cannot set Map field

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a simple bean like this:

```
class Account {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Map<String, String> extras;

    String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    Map<String, String> getExtras() {
        return extras;
    }

    void setExtras(Map<String,String> attr) {
        this.extras=attr;
    }
 }
```

now I'm going to set `extra` by:

```
 Account tmpAccount=new Account();
 tmpAccount.setExtras(new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y"));
```

but I got this error:

```
 setExtras(Map<String,String> in Account cannot be applied to Object.
```

Why?

Comment: Because `new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y")` doesn't bring you the same HashMap, the method `put("x","y")` will rather bring you the last object mapped as "x"

Comment: have you tried to add without using of anonymous object?

Comment: To avoid ugly nullPointException change to `private Map<String, String> extras = Collections.emptyMap();` and set your Strings to ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y")
```

this statement returns a `String` instance

```
void setExtras(Map<String,String> attr)
```

See [`put(K, V)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) API doc for reference

Comment: It will not return `"y"` but the previous mapping for `"x"` and since there wasn't any, it will return `null`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, the issue is you can't chain the HashMap put,

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
tmpAccount.setExtras(map.put("x","y"));
```

Per the [Map#put() method defintion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29),

> V put(K key, V value)

It returns `V`, not `Map`. And `setExtras(map);` takes a `Map` (not a `String`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Account tmpAccount=new Account();
tmpAccount.setExtras(new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y"));
```

will not work. Use as below

```
  Account tmpAccount=new Account();
  Map<String, String> myExtras = new HashMap<String, String>();
  myExtras.put("x","y");
  tmpAccount.setExtras(myExtras);
```

Reason, HashMap's put method signature is as below

```
 public V put(K key,V value)
```

and the value it returns is

```
Returns:
        the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can      
         also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)
```

So, when you do

```
tmpAccount.setExtras(new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y"));
```

You are setting null to setExtras where as it is expecting a HashMap

Answer (score 0):

[.put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. You should do something like this:

```
Account tmpAccount=new Account();
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("x","y");
tmpAccount.setExtras(values);
```

Comment: No, `put()` returns the previous mapping for the key inserted, if any, or `null` if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that I just found, casting to Map:

```
  tmpAccount.setExtras(Map<String, String>)new HashMap<String, String>().put("x","y"));
```

It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Method `put()` returns a string object while the method `setExtras(Map m)` is expecting an object of calls `Map`, Try the following :)

```
    Account tmpAccount = new Account();
    Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("x", "y");
    tmpAccount.setExtras(map);
```